# Is autoboxing possible for the classes I create?

Tags: java, autoboxing

Is there any way to use autoboxing for the classes I create? For example, I have this subclass of `Number`.

```
public class UnsignedInteger extends Number {
    int n;

    public UnsignedInteger(int n) {
        if(n >= 0)
            this.n = n;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only positive integers are supported");
    }
}
```

Now, `UnsignedInteger i = new UnsignedInteger(88);` works perfectly fine, but is there any way to make this compile : `UnsignedInteger i = 88;`? It won't for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good news for this question. I've just filed a feature request to Oracle for adding support for the above syntax. Let's hope it gets accepted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In short, no.  There's no way to get that to compile.

Java only defines a limited set of pre-defined boxing conversions.

From the [JLS, section 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to corresponding expressions of reference type. Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:
>
> - From type boolean to type Boolean
> - From type byte to type Byte
> - From type short to type Short
> - From type char to type Character
> - From type int to type Integer
> - From type long to type Long
> - From type float to type Float
> - From type double to type Double
> - From the null type to the null type

Additionally, one might think of overloading the `=` operator to perform this conversion, but operator overloading is not supported in Java, unlike in C++, where this would be possible.

So your conversion is not possible in Java.

Comment: We could think that java overloads the operator +,*, or /,- but this actually autoboxing for operating with that. See the oracle spec https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 12):

No, unfortunately. [Automatic boxing conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) (as per [JLS §5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)) are only defined for the standard [primitive wrapper classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class).

Answer (score 1):

In short : No, it's not possible. For this to work, you need operator overloading, which is not available in Java. See [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Groovy, you can set the boolean behavior by implementing the asBoolean method: http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_customizing_the_truth_with_asboolean_methods

Example:

```
class Color {
    String name

    boolean asBoolean(){
        name == 'green' ? true : false
    }
}

assert new Color(name: 'green')
assert !new Color(name: 'red')
```

I know this is not plain Java but compiles to bytecode and runs on the JVM.