# Java assignment operator overloading

Tags: java, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I know that Java doesn't support operator overloading, but I saw that you can assign value to an Integer object,for example, with the `=` operator and not by using a setter.

So I was wondering is it possible to implement such behavior to any class?

Comment: You can use the `=` on any class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17619724/1288

Comment: Your question is _extremely_ unclear.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No.  Those assignments only work on Java Primitive Wrappers (Integer, Long, etc) and String.

Comment: Ok. Thanks there !

Comment: This is completely false; any type can be assigned.

Comment: @SLaks I think he means `Long x = 0` for example.

Comment: You're talking about auto-boxing, which has nothing to do with `String`.  It is very unclear that that's what the question is about.

Comment: @Slaks I answered his question and he was very happy about it.

Comment: It's still wrong; if you're talking about auto-boxing, it doesn't apply to `String`.