# Why doesn't the Integer class need an instance created?

Tags: java, integer, autoboxing

I'm trying to figure out why you can do

```
Integer name = 1245;
```

and not need an instance created like this

```
Integer name = new Integer(1245);
```

Is it possible to create a class that doesn't need an instance created? And if you can create a class like that, how would you do it?  I'm looking for something like

```
AsDigits digits = 1245;
```

instead of having to do

```
AsDigits digits = new AsDigits(1245);
```

Comment: [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). No. You cannot add autoboxing for a user defined type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java

Comment: Gotcha.  Thank you.  That definitely put me on the right track.

Comment: With java 10 you can write var digits = new AsDigits(1245) which isn’t too verbose.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to the `Autoboxing`. From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing.

Also, `Autoboxing` cannot be done for user-defined type. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619724/is-autoboxing-possible-for-the-classes-i-create)