# Is possible to do that with my own Object (Integer ad = 8; and Integer ad = 8;)

Tags: java

In java it's possible to do that;

```
String a = "aaaa";
Integer b = 1;
```

and also that;

```
String a = new String("hello ");
Integer ad = new Integer(8);
```

first question : why is that possible and what's name of this standard ?

second question : explain how to work this special case ?

Third question : Is possible to do the same with my own object ?
for example :

`Person p = "Med";`  in place to do that `Person p = new Person("Med");`

Comment: `String` and primitives  are special, you can initiialize them with literals. You can't do that with any other classes.

Comment: No, not really. This is a feature of the compiler. Note that a `Person` could be a complex object. In such cases, it makes no sense of using an assignment operator. The closest you could get in achieving this is using DSLs. New JVM languages provide these features.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html The reason the first integer assignment works, provided you mean `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks but why String don't have a primitive and works like that ?

Comment: see also: [Is autoboxing possible for the classes I create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619724/is-autoboxing-possible-for-the-classes-i-create)

Comment: @Jesper  why String don't have a primitive type and works fine ?

Comment: Because `String` is treated specially by the Java compiler. There is no way to do a similar thing with your own classes.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help ?

Comment: Read about `String Pool` in Java : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings