# I need Java Custom Autoboxing

Tags: java, autoboxing

Is it possible to define custom autoboxing in Java?

I need to automatically convert `java.lang.Number` into my class `org.expr.NumberExpression` when typing parameters of a function. For **two** parameters, I ended up writing **four** very similar methods:

```
public class Assemble {

  public NumberExpression add(NumberExpression a, NumberExpression b) {
    // do something
  }

  public NumberExpression add(NumberExpression a, Number b) {
    return add(a, new NumberConstant(b));
  }

  public NumberExpression add(Number a, Number b) {
    return add(new NumberConstant(a), new NumberConstant(b));
  }

  public NumberExpression add(Number a, NumberExpression b) {
    return add(new NumberConstant(a), b);
  }

}
```

So I can type:

```
assemble.add(5, assemble.add(7, 3));
assemble.add(5, assemble.add(7, 3), 8, 15); // does not work
```

However, I think this becomes unmanageable for 10 parameters (that I wanted to do); I guess I would need to write 1024 similar methods.

The other solution I was thinking about is to write a method like:

```
  public NumberExpression add(NumberExpression... numbers) {
    // do something
  }
```

But would I be able to type `Number` and `NumberExpression` mixed together as parameters?

Comment: No, that is not possible. Autoboxing/unboxing is a language feature, it cannot be customized.

Comment: Most likely you'll need to create a converter in your `NumberExpression` class that takes a `Number` and creates a `NumberExpression`.

Comment: Or you need some kind of preprocessor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is autoboxing possible for the classes I create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619724/is-autoboxing-possible-for-the-classes-i-create)

Comment: "No, that is not possible" -- Sigh.

Comment: The cleanest workaround is probably to define a static method that creates a new `NumberConstant` and do an `import static` so you can write something like `const(8)` instead of `new NumberConstant(8)`.

Comment: Mixed param for vararg is not possible, you can create a static method to return `NumberExpression` from Number and pass as parameter.

Comment: Can't you have your NumberExpression extend Number and declare `NumberExpreassion add(Number... numbers)`

Comment: @Turo "Can't you have your NumberExpression extend Number..." -- Didn't think of that. I'll think about this.

Comment: @Turo I realized I cannot extend Number, since the NumberExpression already extends ScalarExpression, that in turn extends Expression.

Comment: Last Idea: Composition over Inheritance, can't your NumberExpresion only have a ScalarExpression, but I suppose that would bring other trouble...

Answer (score 2):

1. As people said it can't be done
2. How your problem usually solved is you wrap the values yourself and have only one method (look at BigDecimal)

```
assemble.add(
    new IntegerConstant(5),
    assemble.add(new IntegerConstant(7), new IntegerConstant(3))
```

or using a factory:

```
assemble.add(
    NumberExpression.of(5),
    assemble.add(NumberExpression.of(7), NumberExpression.of(3))
```

where:

```
   class NumberExpression {
       public static IntegerConstant of(Integer v) {
           //...
       }

       public static DoubleConstant of(Double v) {
           //...
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't define custom autoboxing